# What should I set LR to before calling main() in an embedded processor?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded

So I'm trying to write a baremetal OS on an armV7 cortex-a8 using GCC and I ran into a bit of a problem.

After I finished setting up the C environment in assembly and jumped to main, I noticed my stack frame was not being kept track of properly. On further inspected it looks like the LR register is being pushed onto the stack as the function that called main() and it's screwing up the debugger.

Problem goes away if I set LR to 0 - but is this the proper way of dealing with this?

Comment: Might be useful to include a fragment of your start-up code - the preparation and call to `__main` and the handling if `__main` should return.  Typically if main returns, you call an endless-loop, force a reset, or call an exception handler - either way, LR will not be used, so it matters little what you set it to, but the debugger has little choice that to interpret it if it is non-null since it has otherwise no knowledge of the call depth.

Comment: May be you can change instruction from ```BL main``` to ```B main``` from assembly. See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/Cihfddaf.html for more information.

Comment: Zero is typical for the older ARM ABI (APCS and `-mapcs-frame`).  The AAPCS can be marked with 'cant undwind', but then you embedded bare metal binary needs lots of exception tables, at least where a stack trace will take place.  So, the answer depends.  [Here is an interesting  approach](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/ArmStackUnwinding/).

Answer (score 2):

The document [Exception handling ABI for the ARM architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0038b/IHI0038B_ehabi.pdf)  suggests this:

> The runtime environment must ensure a stack unwind cannot proceed beyond the valid stack region, possibly by marking the caller of `main()` as `EXIDX_CANTUNWIND`.

This should happen if you use the `.cantunwind` directive in your startup code.